# Arithmetic Operation for a Dataframe and Series with Unmatched Index in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing some arethmetic operations between a dataframe and a series and I don't understand the output. Can somebody explain why I am getting 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, and 12.0 under column e instead of 1.0, 4.0, 7.0, and 10.0 given the second item (e) in the series is equal to 1.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12.).reshape((4, 3)), columns=list('bde'), index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])

         b   d   e
Utah    0.0 0.0 0.0
Ohio    3.0 3.0 3.0
Texas   6.0 6.0 6.0
Oregon  9.0 9.0 9.0

series2 = pd.Series(range(3), index=['b', 'e', 'f'])

b    0
e    1
f    2
dtype: int64

frame + series2

      b   d   e   f
Utah 0.0 NaN 3.0 NaN
Ohio 3.0 NaN 6.0 NaN
Texas 6.0 NaN 9.0 NaN
Oregon 9.0 NaN 12.0 NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the output of `frame`?

Comment: Yes. It is the chunk under `frame`.

Comment: No, they are not the same.

Comment: That's weird. I tried it again. I still get the same output. Can you show me what you got?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from what **actually** contains *frame*:

```
          b     d     e
Utah    0.0   1.0   2.0
Ohio    3.0   4.0   5.0
Texas   6.0   7.0   8.0
Oregon  9.0  10.0  11.0
```

So when you add *series2* to *frame* then for each row from *frame*:

- first there occurs alignment between the current row and
  elements from *series2*,
- then the addition occurs.

Maybe it is easier to say what has been going on for each column:

1. Column *b* (from row in *frame*) is aligned with element *b* from
   *series2*. It contains *0*, so the result of addition is just the same
   as in column *b*.
2. Column *e* (from row in *frame*) contains *2.0*, *5.0*, *8.0* and
   *11.0*. When you add *1* (value from *series2* with index == "e"),
   the result is by one greater than the original value.
3. Columns *d* and *f* are filled with *NaN* because they occur only
   in one of source objects (*d* only in *frame* and *f* only in *series2*).